# How to make Emscripten to link popen

Tags: emscripten

I use the latest emscripten to compile/link a simple program in a file t.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = popen("ls *", "r");
    return 0;
}
```

I do something like this:

emcc t.c -o t.html

The emscripten gives "error: undefined symbol: popen"

I know I could use '-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0' to hide the error, but that will defeat the very purpose of using the popen to do its job. When you load t.html, you will see the missing popen error, of course.

Are all the functions in the stdio.h implemented in emscripten? If not, could you advise me of the correct approach to make the missing functions such as popen work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Running `ls` command doesn't make sense at the beginning.

Your Emscripten C code run in a web browser, not by in an operating system. The Web Browser environment does not provide any UNIX commands and does not allow running any programs outside of the browser. Thus Emscripten does not support multiprocessing.

Comment: You're right. The "ls" command does not make sense. But that is not my point. The command is just a silly example to illustrate the link problem. My point is why the popen is undefined and how the problem can be solved. After some research, I think the Emscripten developers have made a decision to skip some libc functions that they deem irrelevant in the browser context. I wish they could have produced a release note to state which libc functions are undefined so that users would avoid them.

Comment: My point is `popen` is undefined because is *impossible* to implement UNIX process in a browser context so you simply can not solve the problem. It is much better to leave it undefined than to define a non-functional code. I agree that Emscripten documentation is not great and is very confusing but it is not hard to guess that why `popen` is not defined considering the browser's and WemAssembly engine's capabilities.

Comment: Great. Thanks for clarifying your point of view. I will mark the question answered. You may have a point that they should leave those functions undefined. The little inconvenience I had is that I got a lot of them when I tried to build a huge legacy system. I don't even need to call those functions, but I have to deal with them just to get the system built. If I use RROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0, I am afraid I would fail to catch some legitimate undefined functions. Alas, there is no perfect world.

Comment: While the browser itself does not provide `popen()`, WebAssembly can also be executed by Node JS, which may implement it. Furthermore, you could even provide your custom implementation of `popen()` in the browser, e.g. by asking the user to run the command for you, or even by running it on a remote system via some RPC. The point is, it is up to the user (as in: the developer) to provide a `popen()` implementation on the web, but it might still be possible. That is why `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_popen` might be a better approach here.